# Javascript For Loop with 2 sets of parenthesis (round brackets) - FOR ()()

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I just got a code from somewhere, which I trying to understand. But I stuck on a place which I can not understand. Javascript code is as below:

```
for(t_var=0,n_var=i_var.length; t_var<n_var; t_var++)
  (e_var=i_var[t_var])[0]
    .removeEventListener(e_var[1],d_var)
```

It is a single line javascript for loop. I can not understand the use of 2nd set of round bracket i.e. contains **(e_var=i_var[t_var])**. I think it might be creating some sort of array because **[0]** after 2nd set of parenthesis shows it as an array. But I am not sure what is its exact use?

Can anyone help with it please?

Regards

Comment: `for (...) { (e_var = i_var[t_var])[0].removeEventListener(...) }`, `(e_var = i_var[t_var])[0]` is the same as `e_var = i_var[t_var]; e_var[0].removeEventListener(...)`

Comment: _"The simple assignment operator (`=`) is used to assign a value to a variable. The assignment operation **evaluates to the assigned value**."_

Comment: assign `i_var[t_var]` to `e_var` , so `removeEventListener(e_var[1],d_var)` can use e_var directly

Comment: it looks like a mssuse of the grouping operator `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the code in the following manner to make it better understandable:

```js
for(t_var=0,n_var=i_var.length; t_var<n_var; t_var++)(e_var=i_var[t_var])[0].removeEventListener(e_var[1], d_var);

// on multiple lines
for (t_var = 0, n_var = i_var.length; t_var < n_var; t_var++)
  (e_var = i_var[t_var])[0].removeEventListener(e_var[1], d_var);

// using a for-loop with curly brackets
for (t_var = 0, n_var = i_var.length; t_var < n_var; t_var++) {
  (e_var = i_var[t_var])[0].removeEventListener(e_var[1], d_var);
}

// splitting assignment and event listener removal
for (t_var = 0, n_var = i_var.length; t_var < n_var; t_var++) {
  e_var = i_var[t_var];
  e_var[0].removeEventListener(e_var[1], d_var);
  // ^ the expression `(e_var = i_var[t_var])` returns the value assigned to `e_var`
}

// removal of array length caching to make the loop more readable
for (t_var = 0; t_var < i_var.length; t_var++) {
  e_var = i_var[t_var];
  e_var[0].removeEventListener(e_var[1], d_var);
}

// more descriptive variable names
for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  arrayElement = array[index];
  arrayElement[0].removeEventListener(arrayElement[1], eventListener);
}

// using destructuring assignment
for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  arrayElement = array[index];
  const [htmlElement, eventType] = arrayElement;
  htmlElement.removeEventListener(eventType, eventListener);
}

// using for...of instead of standard for-loop
for (const [htmlElement, eventType] of array) {
  htmlElement.removeEventListener(eventType, eventListener);
}
```

Note that your example doesn't use `var`, `let`, or `const` to define the variables. The changes above doesn't use those either except for the new variables introduced by me. Normally variables should always be defined using 1 of the 3 keywords (preferably `let` or `const`), otherwise the variables are global. Global variables often lead to unexpected behaviour, resulting in bugs.

Comment: _"removal of array length caching to make the loop more readable"_ - That change is useless. There are good reasons for a second variable declaration in the header of the loop, escpecially with `let` and `const`

Comment: @Andreas The only good reason for caching the length is the following scenario: You want to use the original array length, but the loop mutates the array causing it to grow or shrink in size. However because the contents of the loop don't change the array size (in the presented senario) we can safely assume that `n_var` will always be the same as `i_var.length`. Meaning that caching the value will only introduce visual complexity, resulting in less readable code.